# How to clear "application cache" in chrome on ipad

Tags: html, ipad, google-chrome, offline, application-cache

I did **`clear all`** in chrome's **setting->privacy**, and then fully closed chrome and turned on the air mode. Then, reopen the chrome, visit the page that previously has been cached by [HTML5 Offline](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/workingoffthegrid/) and it worked

(I expect it to be broken, because I did **`clear all`**)

Looks like the only way to remove the application cache i am aware of is to uninstall/reinstall chrome app. But I suppose it's not the ideal way.

Does anybody know how to do that? much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click the right top setting button.
2. Bottom Click "clear Browsing Data".
3. Click clear cache from the next modal window.

Enjoy.

Answer (score -1):

Open the AppCache Internals page of Chrome (chrome://appcache-internals/) and delete your app.
The complete local storage will be wiped for that app.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. Did you try to go into chrome://appcache-internals/ on iPad Chrome? As I was not able to reach that page.